# Calling another returned function in the same module

Tags: javascript, module

I have a module like this:

```
var myMod = function() {
   return {
       f_a: function() {}
       f_b: function() {}
   }
})();
```

I need to call `f_b` from `f_a`, and I do not know what is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var myMod = (function() {
   return {
       f_a: function() {console.log('hi from f_a');},
       f_b: function() {this.f_a();}
   }
})();

myMod.f_b();
```

You can do it like this

```
var myMod = (function() {
   return {
       f_a: function() {console.log('hi from f_a');},
       f_b: function() {this.f_a();}
   }
})();

myMod.f_b();
```

Comment: actually you can run the code snippet above it is working maybe some syntax error you have please copy the above code and try again

Comment: Is the order of the function declarations considerable?

Comment: I mean f_a and f_b. Can I declare f_a before f_b and then call f_b from f_a?

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra `)()`.It seems you want create an immediately invoking function expression.

```js
var myMod = function() {
  return {
    f_a: function() {
      console.log('f_a')
    },
    f_b: function() {
      console.log('f_b');
    }
  }
};

console.log(myMod().f_a())
```

If you want to call f_b from f_b then use `this`.Actually if you see correctly it this function is returning an `object`. In javascript inside an object to refer to it's property using `this`

```js
var myMod = function() {
  return {
    f_a: function() {
      console.log('f_a')
    },
    f_b: function() {
      this.f_a();
      console.log('f_b');
    }
  }
};

console.log(myMod().f_b())
```

Comment: Thanks, but what about calling f_b from f_a inside the module?

Comment: do you mean to call `f_a` from `f_b`?

Comment: Yes. I need to call f_a from f_b or viceversa